# Why don't I receive mail although I get a 250 OK response?

Tags: smtp

I'm trying to send a mail with telnet. Everything seems to be OK but I don't receive the mail.

Here is what I do inside my terminal on Debian 8:

```
telnet localhost smtp
220 simon ESMTP Exim 4.84_2 Tue, 07 Jun 2016 18:45:24 +0200
HELO 85.170.206.70
250 simon Hello localhost [::1]
mail from: me@gmail.com
250 OK
rcpt to: simongarnier07@hotmail.fr
250 Accepted
data    
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Test message

content

.
250 OK id=1bAK8U-0002ej-DJ

QUIT
```

As you can see I get a SMTP status code 250 but I never receive any mail (even in the undesirable mails folder).

I also tested with RCPT to: `<simongarnier07@hotmail.fr>` but without result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: I don't have this file on my system but I didn't check any other log files.

Comment: Right now all you know is that exim *received* the message. You need to look into exim's log files to find out what exim did with the messages. `exim -bp` might provide clues, too.

Comment: The messages are frozen: "1.1K 1bAK6E-0001VE-Gl <> *** frozen ***"

Comment: I'm "linking" this to this question with helpful answers: https://serverfault.com/questions/867407/postfix-what-does-queued-mail-for-delivery-mean